# Return empty char

Tags: c++

Below is a loop to replace consecutive `__` with `_` in a string (Name and Identity are `std::strings`'s).

```
for(std::string::const_iterator it=Name.begin(); it!= Name.end();++it)
  Identity += (*it == '_' && *std::next(it, 1) == '_')?21:*it;
```

`21` represents `negative acknowledge` in the ASCII table (tried returning others too like `0, '\0'`, leaving the return when true empty). But when this string is written to a text file there is a special character in place of the extra `_` like so `b0^U_fifo`(where ^U is in place of the duplicate `_` I am trying to remove).

How does one return a "nothing" char?

Comment: `*std::next(it, 1)` is UB when `it = Name.end()-1` -> out of bounds access. Also, this doesn't work when the string contains "___" (three in a row).

Comment: simply don't use the ternary operator, but a good ol' if else, that either adds a `char` or not?

Comment: Don't abuse the poor conditional operator. It's for choosing between two values. If you don't have two values to choose from, don't use it.

Comment: Note `^U` is the [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for the control character with code 21 ("U" being the 21st letter), exactly the value in the sample code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, good old if does work.

Comment: @JHBonarius Should be no problem, as `std::string` includes final NUL character (after defect report) and && prevents evaluation of second expression. Three in a row also work as only the last one is considered instead of the first one.

Comment: @Sebastian what if the final character is an underscore? Are you familiar with the sudoedit bug? Similar cause. And dereferencing `string.end()` is still UB (read e.g. [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end) : _"attempting to access it results in undefined behavior."_). The language doesn't make an exception. You have no guarantees.

Comment: Okay, accessing 1 after the length is only allowed with []; https://eel.is/c++draft/string.access specifically distinguishes between pos < size and pos == size. If dereferencing `end()` was legal, they would not have needed a distinction of cases.

Comment: @JHBonarius would `(&*it)[1]` be valid for `it = Name.end() - 1`? The string has a required NUL char accessible by `data()` or `[]`. Calls to both keep the iterators valid.

Comment: @Sebastian that should be legal,  but I'm not 100% sure. Dereferencing `string.end()` should still not be made legal, as it could be an ABI break. In the implementation the closing NUL could be made a separate member, apart from the char-array. From the outside data or indexed access looks like a C array, but internally is different. All kinds of compiler optimizations can be in place that would break. Algorithms might break. A lot a quite smart people have thought about this a lot. You're not the first bringing this up. It will not change.

Comment: I do not (specifically) wish to change it. I could imagine a standard lib, which throws or aborts, whenever `end()` or any other iterator out of range is dereferenced. The addition and subtraction of iterators could be implemented without range check. That would be perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let them tell you not to use the ternary operator. It is perfectly fine. You want to do branchless programming :-)

With `std::pair`

```
std::string temp(Name.length(), '\0');
std::string::iterator tit = temp.begin();

for(std::string::const_iterator it = Name.begin(); it != Name.end(); ++it)
    std::tie(tit, *tit) = make_pair(*it == '_' && std::next(it, 1) != Name.end() && *std::next(it, 1) == '_' ?
            tit : tit + 1, *it);

std::string Identity(temp.begin(), tit);
```

or joking use of ternary operator:

```
std::string Identity;

for(std::string::const_iterator it = Name.begin(); it!= Name.end(); ++it)
  *it == '_' && std::next(it, 1) != Name.end() && *std::next(it, 1) == '_' ?
        std::string() : Identity += *it;
```

or more serious use of ternary operator:

```
std::string Identity;

for(std::string::const_iterator it = Name.begin(); it!= Name.end(); ++it)
  Identity += (*it == '_' && std::next(it, 1) != Name.end() && *std::next(it, 1) == '_') ?
        std::string() : std::string(1, *it);
```

Edit: Additional check to prevent dereferencing Name.end()

Comment: Genius! What does std::string() return?

Comment: Hey, it was more meant like a working (!) joke :-) std::string() returns an empty string; the optimizer probably discards it; we have to specify it, as it needs the same type as `Identity += *it`. Basically we misused the ternary operator to execute normal instructions.

Comment: I added a more serious variant, where the returned value of the ternary operator is actually used. It concatenates a `std::string` to `Identity` instead of a `char`. A `std::string` can be empty.

Answer (score 5):

> How does one return a "nothing" char?

One doesn't return a "nothing" char since such char doesn't exist.

Instead of trying to insert a "nothing" char, you should probably be "not inserting" a char. Perhaps something like this:

```
if (*it != '_' || *std::next(it, 1) != '_')
    Identity += *it;
```

Comment: This works. I was trying too hard to accomplish this in 1 one line. Turns out that's not. easy

Comment: @zoulzubazz `(*it == '_' && *std::next(it, 1) == '_') ? Identity : Identity += *it;` does what you want, but I wouldn't do it

Answer (score 1):

> to replace consecutive __ with _

The problem is that the string to be replaced and the replacement differ in length – still you are lucky as the replacement string is shorter than what it replaces, thus you won't need to re-allocate any memory.

Now when you replace a double underscore with a single one there remains a gap. Instead of trying to fill it with some dummy value you might rather move the subsequent characters towards the end of the resulting string, which might look as follows (in-place replacement within the string, i. e. you don't enforce creation of a copy if this is not necessary):

```
if(!theString.empty())
{
    auto pos = theString.begin();
    for(auto cur = std::next(pos); cur != theString.end(); ++cur)
    {
        if(*cur != '_' || *pos != '_')
        {
            *++pos = *cur;
        }
    }
    theString.resize(std::distance(theString.begin(), pos) + 1);
}
```

Note that this replaces longer sequences of underscores with a single one as well. If this is not intended the loop needs some adjustments, but the basic idea remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `find()`+`substr()` loop, eg:

```cpp
string::size_type start = 0, end;

while ((end = Name.find("__", start)) != std::string::npos)
{
    Identity += Name.substr(start, (end + 1) - start);
    start = end + 2;
}

if (start < Name.size())
    Identity += Name.substr(start);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/yzknlv)